# Eclipse Builders: Verify Return Code?

Tags: java, eclipse, builder

So, our java codebase is so complex that we can't use Eclipse's incremental compilation feature and instead use a script called "intern" with argument build. Because of this, I added a program builder to Eclipse with the path to intern and the single argument build:
[image: intern build]

However, if I press F11 to Debug, and the build fails, Eclipse happily ignores this and continues to launch the program, even though I had allocated a console under build options. Any ideas on how to stop the Debug launch if the build fails?

One idea I have (but which may not work) is to make the builder run a custom script which runs `intern build` and pauses if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one replied, I just ended up:

1. Modifying the `bin/intern` script to add an `-eclipse_build` parameter, which, if present, will invoke `read -p "Build failed"` on failure (to display "Build failed" and pause the console).
2. Changing the arguments in the builder to be `build -eclipse_build`

This is working fine for me.
Hope this helps future searchers!